# Нужно ли перед и после "некорректный" ставить какие-то знаки препинания, кроме кавычек?

Tags: пунктуация, кавычки

Кстати, слово "некорректный" пишется слитно.

Answer (score 2):

В Вашем предложении сло­во "кста­ти" грам­ма­ти­че­ски не свя­зан­о с дру­ги­ми чле­на­ми пред­ло­же­ния. Оно обо­зна­ча­ет после­до­ва­тель­ность тече­ния мыс­лей и их связь. В этом слу­чае "кстати" явля­ет­ся ввод­ным сло­вом и обя­за­тель­но выде­ля­ет­ся запя­той в нача­ле пред­ло­же­ния:
*Кстати, он был заме­ча­тель­но хорош собой, с пре­крас­ны­ми тем­ны­ми гла­за­ми, темно-рус, ростом выше сред­не­го, тонок и стро­ен* (Ф. М. Достоевский. Преступление и нака­за­ние).
[**кстати**](http://russkiiyazyk.ru/orfografiya/pravopisanie/slovo-kstati-kak-pishetsya.html)

У Вас написано все правильно:
**Кстати, слово "некорректный" пишется слитно.**

Возможен и такой вариант написания (с выделением курсивом):
Кстати, слово *некорректный* пишется слитно.

Comment: Спасибо я думал возможно это предложение пишется так.
Кстати, слово, - "некорректный", пишется слитно.

Comment: Или так будет не правильно?

Comment: Неправильно. Кроме "кстати" здесь нечего обособлять, а постановка лишних знаков препинания считается ошибкой.